# Why the differences in memory address or offset between xxd and objdump?

Tags: x86, reverse-engineering, elf, objdump, xxd

I have the following test assembly program:

```
.section .rodata
a: .byte 17

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $1, %eax
    mov a(%rip), %ebx
    int $0x80
```

And I've compiled into an executable called `file`. When I use `objdump` to disassemble I get the following expected output:

```
$ objdump --disassemble --section=.text file

file:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400078 <_start>:
  400078:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40007d:   8b 1d 02 00 00 00       mov    0x2(%rip),%ebx        # 400085 <a>
  400083:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

However, when I just print the binary with `$ xxd file` the memory doesn't even go up to `400078`:

```
00000000: 7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
00000010: 0200 3e00 0100 0000 b000 4000 0000 0000  ..>.......@.....
00000020: 4000 0000 0000 0000 e001 0000 0000 0000  @...............
...
00000340: 2700 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  '...............
00000350: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

What accounts for the differences in this? It seems like `xxd` just offsets everything from 0, but then what 'offset' if you can call it that does `objdump` use? How can I reconcile where `400078` would be in `xxd`? Or do I need to use another program for that?

Comment: xxd is a hexdump of the file, those are file offsets.  It doesn't know anything about ELF metadata not memory addresses.  It's just a simple hex-dump of arbitrary binary data.

Comment: Use objdump -h to show the headers of the ELF file. That will tell you the offset in the file corresponding to the text section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the differences in memory address or offset between xxd and objdump?

Because they show you largely unrelated views of the data.

- `xxd` shows you the raw bits of an arbitrary file, with no interpretation of their meaning.
- `objdump` (with the flags you used) shows you what the contents of *memory* would look like when your executable is loaded into memory.

  `objdump` arrives at that view by examining and *understanding* the meaning of the `ELF` file header, program headers and section headers.

You can use `readelf --segments` and `readelf --sections` to examine these headers.

Comment: Never use `objdump`?  I don't see a disassembly option in `readelf`'s man page.  Did you mean never use for some specific purpose, or some of its options?  Like never use `objdump -h`?

Comment: @PeterCordes You are correct. I toned the answer down.